# XML Formatting Skipping Field

Tags: xml

Apologies for any formatting issues, it's been a while since I've come to StackOverflow.

I have an integration setup between a couple of systems that utilizes SQL Server to build an XML file for import into another system.  I'm getting a kickback from the importing system that a field is required to have an alphanumeric between 1-7500 in length.  As far as I can tell, everything exists that needs to be there.  Unfortunately, the importing system doesn't provide any other information.

I don't see any issues with the snippet below, but are there any glaring issues with this XML that could possibly cause a field to be blank or skipped?  I.e. like a CSV has a carriage return hiding causing a row break.

*Formatting has stayed the same with relevant information hidden*

Thank you. (The Complaint, Cause, and Correction fields are just text blobs, the data is not being pulled out into fields based on the label name)

```
<IKM_RepairOrder>
  <UserName>JohnDoe</UserName>
  <Branch>9999</Branch>
  <Department>EMS</Department>
  <RepairOrder>99999999</RepairOrder>
  <Customer>999999</Customer>
  <Unit>MISC</Unit>
  <MeterReading>0</MeterReading>
  <RODate>2023-04-04T14:45:38</RODate>
  <CustomerPO>TECH: 9999</CustomerPO>
  <IKM_RepairOrderTasks>
    <IKM_RepairOrderTask>
      <Task>1</Task>
      <RepairGroup>EMS</RepairGroup>
      <RepairType>EMSBRK</RepairType>
      <BillingHours>3.00</BillingHours>
      <Complaint>WO #: 99999999; DRIVER: DOE; CONTRACTOR NAME: ; REPAIR DATE: 4/4/2023 2:45:38 PM; METER: 0; PO: NEED; REF: N/A; PROBLEM: RIGHT SIDE, REAR MUDFLAP AND BRACKET NEED REPLACED  YARD HOURS:7:30AM:6:00PM</Complaint>
      <Cause>B: 2; CUSTOMER: ABC COMP; YEAR/COLOR: 2018; MAKE/MODEL: FONTAINE; VIN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;TRUCK: ; TRAILER: XXXXXXX; TECH NAME: JOHN DOE; ADDRESS: ABC ROAD; CITY: BLANK, CITY; STATE: AZ</Cause>
      <Correction>FOUND THAT BRACKET WAS GONE I FABRICATED A NEW BRACKET AND MOUNTED NEW MUD FLAP TO BRACKET </Correction>
      <IKM_RepairOrderLabors>
        <IKM_RepairOrderLabor>
          <Technician>7758</Technician>
          <LaborHours>3.00</LaborHours>
        </IKM_RepairOrderLabor>
      </IKM_RepairOrderLabors>
      <IKM_RepairOrderParts>
        <IKM_RepairOrderPart>
          <PartNumber>PNS</PartNumber>
          <Description>3X16 ANGLE IRON </Description>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Cost>85.98</Cost>
          <Supplier>MM35</Supplier>
        </IKM_RepairOrderPart>
      </IKM_RepairOrderParts>
    </IKM_RepairOrderTask>
  </IKM_RepairOrderTasks>
</IKM_RepairOrder>
```

Comment: May be it's doesn't like trailing whitespace like in Description. May be it's validating against a DTD or XSD

Comment: You need to introduce an XSD to enforce your XML shape and data quality. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will eliminate guess work and ambiguity. Both sides, i.e. sender and receiver, should agree and sign off on the XSD. XSDs are available since 2001.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/validate-xml-with-the-xml-task?view=sql-server-ver16